# How to copy all lines starting with a number in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a document containing titles and codes. Each got their own line and now I need to copy all codes out of it, each in a separate line. They all start with numbers and Vim can probably do it with ease.

The document looks like this:

```
TITLE
123-456-4252-2

Other TITLE 2
123-456-4252-X

A nice TITLE 3
523-456-4252-2

...
```

Comment: Could you add a excerpt of the document? Obfuscated at least.

Comment: @gonzalo Added :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `:global` command!

```
qaq:g/^\d/y A
```

After this, the lines are in the `a` register. Afterwards you can paste the copied lines with `"ap`.

### Explanation:

- `qaq` records a macro in `a` and immediately ends it, effectively clearing it.
- `:g/foo/bar` executes the `bar` command for every line that matches `foo`.
- `^\d` is a regex that matches lines starting with a number.
- `y A` yanks into the `a` register, but in append-mode.

Comment: Thank you so much, vim is so powerful but hard to learn. Thank you for helping noobs like me out :)

Comment: Sometimes it may feel hard to learn, but I find it way easier than remembering a billion keyboard shortcuts, because the vim language (and I _don't_ mean VimScript) is so composable. You don't need to remember the sequence of keystrokes in my answer, but rather the LEGO pieces.

Comment: With a little change you can add the content to the clipboard: `qaq :g/^\d/y A | let @+=@a`